# function error and getting the code to work

Tags: python, bioinformatics

```
def PatternCount(Text,Pattern):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0,1+len(Text)-len(Pattern)):
        if Text[i:i+len(Pattern)] == Pattern:
            count = count + 1
    return count
def Frequentwords(Text,K):
    FrequentPattern = {}
    for i in range(0,len(Text)-K):
        Pattern = Text(i,K)
        Count(i)=PatternCount(Text,Pattern)
    maxCount = max(Count)
    for i in range(0,len(Text)-K):
        if Count(i) == maxCount:
            FrequentPattern.add(Text(i,K))
        list(set(FrequentPattern))
        return FrequentPattern
Text = input("enter DNA sequence: ")
K = int(input("enter the length of the pattern: "))
print(Frequentwords(Text,K))
```

this code is to find the most frequent K-mers (the length of a short DNA sequence) in a string Text(DNA sequences) checks all k-mers appearing in this string (there are |Text| − k + 1 such k-mers) and then computes how many times each k-mer appears in Text.

there is an error in this line:

```
Count(i)=PatternCount(Text,Pattern)
```

it is SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

l want this code to 
Input: A string Text DNA Seguence and an integer k.
Output: All most frequent k-mers in Text

Answer (score 0):

This line `Count(i)=PatternCount(Text,Pattern)` doesn't make sense because you are assigning a function to another function. If `Count` is an array, then it should be like this:

```
Count[i]=PatternCount(Text,Pattern)
```

you should change all `Count(i)` in your code to `Count[i]`. Here's the code fixed:

```
def pattern_count(sequence,pattern):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0,1+len(sequence)-len(pattern)):
        if sequence[i:i+len(pattern)] == pattern:
            count = count + 1
    return count

def frequent_words(sequence,t):
    counters = [0]*len(sequence)
    for i in range(0,len(sequence)-k):
        pattern = sequence[i:i+k]
        counters[i] = pattern_count(sequence,pattern)
    maxCounter = max(counters)
    print(counters)
    for i in range(0,len(sequence)-k):
        if counters[i] == maxCounter:
            frequent_pattern = sequence[i:i+k]
    return frequent_pattern

sequence = input("enter DNA sequence: ")
k = int(input("enter the length of the pattern: "))
print(frequent_words(sequence,k))
```

The base idea was fine, but there were some syntax errors. I also changed some variables names to fit standards.

You could optimize this by doing like this:

```
def frequent_words(sequence,t):
    counters = [0]*len(sequence)
    for i in range(0,len(sequence)-k):
        pattern = sequence[i:i+k]
        counters[i] = pattern_count(sequence,pattern)
    max_index = counters.index(max(counters))
    return sequence[max_index:max_index+k]
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: ok l change the  Count to array but l get this erros
   `print(Frequentwords(Text,K))

    Pattern = Text(i,K)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` how to fix this type of error

Comment: Same problem there. `Text` is a string, and by doing `Text(i, k)` you are telling python to call a function with arguments i and k. I don't know what you want from that line.

Comment: l am trying to  generate an array Count, where Count(i) stores Count(Text, Pattern) for Pattern = Text(i, k)                                                                                                                                       The array Count for Text = ACTGACTCCCACCCC and k = 3. For example, Count(0) = Count(4) = 2 because ACT (shown in boldface) appears twice in Text.

Comment: when l run the edited code with this example: `Sample Input:

ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT
4` it gave me just one frequent word `CATG` and the correct output should gave me two frequent words 

`CATG GCAT` so how can l fix that? thanks for the answer

Comment: Right now the code is returning just one frequent word, if you want all, you'll have to return an array, and append all words avoiding duplicates but I think that's material enough for another question. If this answer helped you, please accept the answer.